# Email @ converted to %40 in GET - Using Swagger UI + Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, spring-restcontroller

I supply a correct email parameter as part of the request in my swagger-ui GET email service, which it is supposed to return a 200 with the the response json object, yet it comes back with a 404 and the email is there in the database, when

I have noticed that it changes the @ to %40 in the url request
http://localhost:8080/EmailApp/user/email/test%40email.com

Below is my restful web service method

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns a user by email", notes = "Returns a user 
and its details by email.", response = User.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of a User", response = User.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "User with given email does not exist"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error")}
)
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/email/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getUserByEmail(@ApiParam(name = "email", value = "The user email", required = true)@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    log.info("Fetching User with email {}", email);
    User user = userService.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null) {
        log.error("User with email {} not found.", email);
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("User with email " + email
                + " not found"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How do I make sure that the @ is preserved in the url request in GET http protocol?

Comment: The @ is, and should be, [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Why do you want to keep the @ in the URL? That would make the URL invalid. Instead of trying to keep the @, decode it using `java.net.URLDecoder` when necessary.

Comment: Thanks I used this and it worked like a charm!